# Correlated subquery to handle multiple rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, group-by, correlated-subquery

Consider a query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates0(date) AS
  (
   VALUES('2022-03-01')
   UNION ALL SELECT date(date, '+1 day')
   FROM dates0
   WHERE date < DATE('2022-03-03')),
               q0 AS
  (SELECT d.date, 
     (
     --pretend this is a result of an expensive subquery for which we need d.date
     SELECT 'Need to insert result of another query here'
     ----pretend this is a result of an expensive subquery for which we need d.date
     
     ) AS vegetables
   FROM dates0 d)
SELECT *
FROM q0;
```

Instead of 'SELECT' between 2 commented lines I need to incorporate result of the following subquery:

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount) AS amount FROM (
     SELECT 'POTATO' AS name,
     '2022-03-03' AS date,
     3 AS amount
     
     UNION
     SELECT 'TURNIP' AS name,
     '2022-03-03' AS date,
     15 AS amount
     
     UNION
     SELECT 'TURNIP' AS name,
     '2022-03-03' AS date,
     25 AS amount) GROUP BY name
```

For the end result:

```
date    potato  turnip
3/1/2022    0   0
3/2/2022    0   0
3/3/2022    3   40
```

PlaceHolderPlaceHolderPlaceHolderPlaceHolderPlaceHolder (sorry, SO otherwise considers the post to have insufficient amount of text)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your query is a CTE named `vegetables`, you can do it with a `LEFT` join of `dates0` to `vegetables` and conditional aggregation:

```
WITH 
  RECURSIVE dates0(date) AS (
    VALUES('2022-03-01')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date(date, '+1 day')
    FROM dates0
    WHERE date < DATE('2022-03-03')
  ),
  vegetables AS (
    SELECT 'POTATO' AS name, '2022-03-03' AS date, 3 AS amount
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'TURNIP' AS name, '2022-03-03' AS date, 15 AS amount
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT 'TURNIP' AS name, '2022-03-03' AS date, 25 AS amount  
  ),
  q0 AS (
    SELECT d.date,
           TOTAL(CASE WHEN v.name = 'POTATO' THEN v.amount END) AS potato,
           TOTAL(CASE WHEN v.name = 'TURNIP' THEN v.amount END) AS turnip
    FROM dates0 d LEFT JOIN vegetables v
    ON v.date = d.date
    GROUP BY d.date
  )
SELECT *
FROM q0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b3a111f740f483aba84b27973167e39e).

Comment: vegetables CTE has to have d.date instead of hardcoded date, hence the difficulty, left it out when editing the answer, sorry!

Comment: @NickFarsi what do you mean? Edit the question to clarify.